# Relation between Confluent Hypergeometric and Bessel Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there any known relation that relates the specific case of Kummer function $U(\nu + \frac{1}{2}, \nu +1, 2z)$ to Bessel $K_\nu(z)$ functions? Or at least to any other Hypergeometric functions? I know that $U(\nu + \frac{1}{2}, 2 \nu +1, 2z)$ simplifies nicely in terms of $K_\nu(z)$.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd check out the book by Bateman (1949). Volume 1. This seems a very complete reference on hypergeometric/bessel connections